# How to convert a string to a date and count the time difference to the current time?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am new to Google App Script. I need to build a function to count the time difference. I got a date string in the format dd.MM.yy HH:mm (11.01.22 16:00). I want to count the difference between this date and =NOW() in the same format. If the difference is less than 8 hours, I want to change the color of the specified cell.

Could someone shed some light on this, and advise how to parse that string date to date format?

Answer (score 0):

#### Difference in hours between column1 and now

```
function diffinhours() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const vs = sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues();
  let nowv = new Date().valueOf();
  let col2=vs.map(d => {
    let t = d.toString().split(/[. :]/);
    return [(new Date(parseInt(20 + t[2]),t[1] - 1,t[0],t[3],t[4]).valueOf() - nowv)/3600000]
  });
  sh.getRange(1,2,col2.length,1).setValues(col2);
}
```

[Date Constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date)

Sheet1:

| Date | Hours |
| --- | --- |
| 01.01.22 00:00 | -277.2126303 |
| 02.01.22 00:00 | -253.2126303 |
| 03.01.22 00:00 | -229.2126303 |
| 04.01.22 00:00 | -205.2126303 |
| 05.01.22 00:00 | -181.2126303 |
| 06.01.22 00:00 | -157.2126303 |
| 07.01.22 00:00 | -133.2126303 |
| 08.01.22 00:00 | -109.2126303 |
| 09.01.22 00:00 | -85.21263028 |
| 10.01.22 00:00 | -61.21263028 |
| 11.01.22 00:00 | -37.21263028 |
| 12.01.22 00:00 | -13.21263028 |
| 13.01.22 00:00 | 10.78736972 |
| 14.01.22 00:00 | 34.78736972 |
| 15.01.22 00:00 | 58.78736972 |
| 16.01.22 00:00 | 82.78736972 |
| 17.01.22 00:00 | 106.7873697 |
| 18.01.22 00:00 | 130.7873697 |
| 19.01.22 00:00 | 154.7873697 |
| 20.01.22 00:00 | 178.7873697 |

> Often the underlying value in a string of this nature is a Date() object and you then don't have to deconstruct the string and create a new date object instead you can just do something like this.  It may look different to you because the numberformat for the cell my be something like "dd.MM.yy HH:mm" and it that is the case then you can take the following easier approach.

```
function diffinhours() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const vs = sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues();
  let nowv = new Date().valueOf();
  let col2=vs.map(d => [(new Date(d).valueOf() - nowv)/3600000]);
  sh.getRange(1,2,col2.length,1).setValues(col2);
}
```